# How to select the data by unicode where condition?

Tags: sql, unicode, ado.net

I would like to get the data base on following SQL Statement and that was located in TableAdapter.

```
SELECT * FROM Student WHERE Chinese_Name = @Param
```

Example code call from C# is like this.

```
GetDataByChinese_Name('你好');
```

But I have no idea where should I put the ***N*** prefix in that syntax. Usually, we can get

```
SELECT * FROM Student WHERE Chinese_Name = N'你好'
```

this way.

Comment: Are you using `nvarchar` fields?  Can you show your table structure (`sp_help Student`)

Comment: @AdamPlocher of course, I used nvarchar(MAX).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your c# code should be slightly different. Use verbatim string literal.([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx))

```
    GetDataByChinese_Name(@"你好");
```