# asp.net turkish character issue

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a Turkish character problem. If my search string contains "İ", it doesnt return the existing data. When I do select statement below in MSSQL TOOL, It works but when I call the same select statement in ASP.NET , it doesnt work.

here is the select

```
select * from product where name like N'%GALVANİZ%'
```

this works in mssql tool and returns the expected data rows. but it doesnt return any data when called in asp.net

how can I get it to return data in asp.net ?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333226/how-to-select-the-data-by-unicode-where-condition

Comment: how you call it on asp.net ? (the code please)

Comment: What is the type of your column in sql? Is it char/varchar or nchar/nvarchar? If former, change to latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Turkish characters make sure that your column is nchar or nvarchar.

Then if you're having problems fetching it at the asp.net side try to change it's encoding to "windows-1254" with `Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1254")`